# How to combine multiple object in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, object

I want to combine my ordered products and display the order list.

Controller :

```
$orders = Order::where('customer_id', 1)->pluck('products');
print_r($orders);
```

This is what I receive:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 
   [
        {"id":3,"product_id":3,"size":"47","quantity":7,"name":"Simple Regular T-shirt","price":2200,"thumbnail":"Thumbnail_614291597.jpg"},
        {"id":7,"product_id":4,"size":"47","quantity":8,"name":"Simple Regular Shirt","price":123,"thumbnail":"Thumbnail_91520734.jpg"}
   ] 

[1] => 
   [
        {"id":9,"product_id":3,"size":"45","quantity":2,"name":"Simple Regular T-shirt","price":2200,"thumbnail":"Thumbnail_614291597.jpg"}
   ] 
)
```

But I want.

```
Array ( 
[0] => 
   [
        {"id":3,"product_id":3,"size":"47","quantity":7,"name":"Simple Regular T-shirt","price":2200,"thumbnail":"Thumbnail_614291597.jpg"},
        {"id":7,"product_id":4,"size":"47","quantity":8,"name":"Simple Regular Shirt","price":123,"thumbnail":"Thumbnail_91520734.jpg"},
        {"id":9,"product_id":3,"size":"45","quantity":2,"name":"Simple Regular T-shirt","price":2200,"thumbnail":"Thumbnail_614291597.jpg"}
   ] 
)
```

How I can do this?

I already tried a different way, but I can't do this. Firstly I was trying to convert it array and then use the array_marge() function for those arrays. but that array needs only two arrays but for my case, it is not specified how many arrays the user has given. And try to solve it with a loop (I just tried). I am new in this field.

Comment: *"I already tried many different ways"* - Like what? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72550373/edit) to show your attempts and specifically what is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in this field. I updated some info. If you know this solution kindly help.

Comment: I meant include the code examples you tried, not describe them... If you can show your attempts, and why they "are not working" (please don't ever just say "It's not working" with no further information like you did on the answer below; that statement is _not_ useful on it's own; **why** is it not working?) then we can better help you. Also, Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. I'm asking you to show what you tried so we can help correct it, and because it is required; you're expected to make and demonstrate an attempt to solve your own issue first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```php
$orders = Order::where('customer_id', 1)
    ->pluck('products')
    ->values()
    ->flatten(1);
```

The **pluck** will return a collection, **flatten** with a depth of **1** will remove the nesting. **values** will reset the keys to sequential - (it's not strictly necessary here)

[Laravel Docs - Collections - Values](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-values)

[Laravel Docs - Collections - Flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-flatten)

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: @CreatiqueIT Please understand just writing "It's not working" doesn't help. When you try the above approach what output do you get - you need to elaborate, can edit your question to write - I tried this and this is what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [`flatten()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-flatten) after applying the query (with `->get()`):

```
$orders = Order::where('customer_id', 1)->get()->pluck('products')->flatten();
print_r($orders);
```

Side note:
Instead of `print_r()` You can use `dump()` to pretty print the output in your browser

```
 $orders->dump(); //only dump
 $orders->dd(); //dump and exit
```

Comment: Alternatively `dump($variable)` or `dd($variable)` if `$variable` doesn't have a `->dump()` or `->dd()` method 

Comment: out of context my friend ;)

Comment: But still useful information to know. `$var = 1;`, then `$var->dump()` is not gonna do anything, while `dump($var)` would. I would lean towards generic usage over type-specific usage 